# Performance in HTML

Tags: html

how to maintain Version for css and Java script in html

how to compress java script in run time

Comment: how to write question

Comment: how to formulate cogent thought

Comment: @Jacob_pgr http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

To compress Javascript in runtime, you can call a server-side page which read your javascript file, *minimize and cache it* and return your compressed file. So you'll have to do something like:

```
<script src="Minimize.aspx?YourJavascriptFile.js"></script>
```

But, if you compress it before upload, you can save some processor cycles and memory.

Answer (score 0):

To remove javascript and css cache, you can add a version number after the file name:

```
<script src="MyMinimizedScript.js?version=1"></script>
```

when you change the javascript (or do the same for css), just change the version number. Your file name does not need to change.